# ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, cmd

I am trying to run a command on cmd "create-react-app hello-world". But as soon as I try to run this command it reflects me an error **"ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER"**
and
**"request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@rollup/pluginutils/-/pluginutils-3.1.0.tgz failed, reason: 10996:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:308:"**

please help me o resolve this.

Comment: this could be because the version of react lib is not compatible with nodejs version try updating the Nodejs  | Npm then then reinstall the react that should solve it

Comment: Can you mention the `nodejs` version and `npm` version you are using?

Comment: nodejs v16.2.0  and npm v7.14.0